# Is there a way to straighten an existing line object in EXCEL?

Tags: microsoft-excel, shapes

Can you make the excel line object straight meaning having the same x-axis value for both points or same y-axis for vertical lines?

I know that you can make a line straight on creation by pressing [Shift] key so it does not slant.

What I am asking is if there is an existing EXCEL chart and I noticed a line is very slightly slant diagonally by just a few pixel.

There are times that, I do not want to re-create the line because it will force me to find the exact point where it starts and end. Is there a way to make the line straight? This is difficult for existing complicated set of shapes inside an excel or word document.

Comment: Is this an object (shape) created in excel? or it is a line in a chart produced in excel? (both are mentioned in your question)

Comment: @p._phidot_ it is an object shape in excel.

Comment: Then I suggest to re-draw a new line (with the [Shift] key) over the old line.. re-position it, and delete the old line. Seems easier that way to me..